# What is the proper json encoding for the kendoui parameterMap to decode php object?

Tags: php, kendo-ui, json

I am having trouble passing a properly encoded json string to a php file as an object.

Going off the kendoui examples provided I have a dataSource that is instantiated like this:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/7/30"),
    startTime: new Date("2013/7/30 07:00 AM"),
    views: [
                "day",
                "week",
                { type: "month", eventHeight: 20, selected: true },
                "agenda"
            ],
    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
    height: $(document).height()-72,
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "scheduler_data_pdo.php?type=read",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "scheduler_data_pdo.php?type=update",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "scheduler_data_pdo.php?type=create",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "scheduler_data_pdo.php?type=destroy",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "taskId",
                fields: {
                    taskId: { from: "taskId", type: "number" },
                    title: { from: "title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                    start: { type: "date", from: "start" },
                    end: { type: "date", from: "end" },
                    startTimezone: { from: "startTimezone" },
                    endTimezone: { from: "endTimezone" },
                    description: { from: "description" },
                    recurrenceId: { from: "recurrenceId" },
                    recurrenceRule: { from: "recurrenceRule" },
                    recurrenceException: { from: "recurrenceException" },
                    ownerId: { from: "ownerId", defaultValue: 1 },
                    isAllDay: { type: "number", from: "isAllDay" }
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

The result here for an update is:

```
models=[{"title":"No title","start":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","startTimezone":"","end":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","endTimezone":"","recurrenceRule":"","recurrenceException":"","isAllDay":true,"description":"","taskId":0,"recurrenceId":"","ownerId":1}]
```

Which is improper JSON....  to sanitize I am running it through this code on the php side:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($request)); 
$request = html_entity_decode($request,null,'UTF-8');
$request = ltrim($request,"models=");
$request = '{"models":'.$request.'}';
$request =json_decode($request);
```

This returns a properly encoded php object from this JSON string:

```
{"models":[{"title":"No title","start":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","startTimezone":"","end":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","endTimezone":"","recurrenceRule":"","recurrenceException":"","isAllDay":true,"description":"","taskId":0,"recurrenceId":"","ownerId":1}]}
```

The question is what am I doing wrong that I have to modify the string being passed.  It seems that it should just be passed as a properly encoded JSON element that I could simply run through

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter map you are using is taken from the Kendo online demos which use a JSONP end point. In your case it would be a lot easier to go like this:

```
        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return kendo.stringify(options.models);
            }
            return kendo.stringify(options);
        }
```

This would send the "models" as a valid JSON array:

```
[{"title":"No title","start":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","startTimezone":"","end":"2013-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","endTimezone":"","recurrenceRule":"","recurrenceException":"","isAllDay":true,"description":"","taskId":0,"recurrenceId":"","ownerId":1}]
```

Comment: Thanks... That definitely helps and makes more sense.  Am I correct in assuming that there is no getting around decoding the POST with this code:    `$request = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($request)); 
$request = html_entity_decode($request,null,'UTF-8');`